# Simple counting problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose that you have a box with $n$ balls, from the $n$ balls $k$ are white and $n-k$ are black. Now, sequentially you draw (without replacement) the $n$ balls in groups of $m$ (a natural number that divides $n$). My question is, what is the probability that in every one of the $n/m$ draws there is at least one white ball?

A first naive idea that I explored is to think that we have $m$ urns and place one white ball in each urn, then count all the possible ways of drawing $n-m$ balls out of which $k-m$ are white and multiply this number by the positions in which we can place the white ball that is already in the urn within the sequence:

$$
\frac{m^{n/m}{n-m\choose k-m}}{n \choose k}
$$

However the above formula is obviously overcounting some sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n=ma$.  The problem is equivalent to forming words
$$x_1x_2\cdots x_mx_{m+1}\cdots x_n$$
over $\{b,w\}$ such that $w$ occurs exactly $k$ times and each of the $a$ subwords
$$x_1\cdots x_m\ ,\quad x_{m+1}\cdots x_{2m}\ ,\ldots$$
contains at least one $w$.  By inclusion/exclusion, the number of such words is
$$\sum_{j=0}^a (-1)^j\!\binom{a}{j}\!\!\!\binom{n-ja}{k}\ .$$